# Is there any way to skip the step "Resolving dependencies" when do mvn build

Tags: maven, dependencies, tycho

I'm building a big project using `Tycho`.

Trying to build offline after one online build is successful, but every time I build, it costs me about 20mins to resolve dependencies.

For other reasons, build  fails and I have to try many times. The wasted time got me crazy. Is there any way I can skip the "Resolving dependencies" step?

Comment: Yes, there is: `-Dtycho.mode=maven`. But then the Tycho build plug-ins won't work any more. If you want more than this simplistic answer, you need to share more details on your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Once you build your project, i.e. you hit the `install` lifecycle phase, Maven will have the dependencies pasted under your local repository.

Unless you force dependencies reloading, *Maven* will go for an offline installation since all dependencies are there (that is the main purpose of saving artifacts locally).
That is the second build should be faster and straightforward.

If you are working within *Eclipse*, make sure it is using a local copy of *Maven*. Otherwise, the `-o` option should be fine if no snapshot dependencies are there:

```
mvn -o
```